# error of "too many indices for array"

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix

I want to produce a 2D matrix `I[x,t]` with two for loops. This is a `70*60` matrix.
I firstly calculate my vectors with one row and 60 columns. Then, in the inner for loop, for every `t` step, I calculate the matrix `I` by using `x` for my `V` which is a vector with one column and 70 rows.
I face with the following error for `I[x,t]`:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I will be glad if someone helps me to correct it.

```
from math import *
from pylab import *
from numpy import *

N=60 #number of cells
Ir=zeros((1,N))
Ir=Ir+1000.0
Temp=zeros((1,N))
Temp=Temp+25.0
V = arange(0,0.7,0.01)
Area=243.36
ns=1
np=1
Jsc_cell = 0.03785
Isc_cell = Jsc_cell * Area
n1=1.0
J01 = 6.2e-13
Is1 = J01 * Area
n2= 2.0
J02 = 7.3e-9
Is2= J02 * Area
T_co = 0.0005
Rs = 2.7487398e-3
Rsh = 410913.8725
k = 1.38e-23
q = 1.6e-19
Eg=1.11
Tmeas= 273+25.0

Iph=zeros((1,N))
I0=zeros((1,N))
I02=zeros((1,N))
Vt=zeros((1,N))
I=zeros((len(V),N))
P=zeros((len(V),N))
T=zeros((1,N))
Pmpp_cell=zeros((1,N))
Impp_cell=zeros((1,N))
Vmpp_cell=zeros((1,N))
Isc_cell_c=zeros((1,N))

for t in range(0,N):
    T[0,t] = Temp[0,t]+273.0
    Vt[0,t]=(k*T[0,t])/q
    I0[0,t]=Is1*((T[0,t]/Tmeas)**(3/n1))*exp(Eg*((T[0,t]/Tmeas)-1)/(n1*Vt[0,t]));
    I02[0,t]=Is2*((T[0,t]/Tmeas)**(3/n2))*exp(Eg*((T[0,t]/Tmeas)-1)/(n2*Vt[0,t]));
    Iph[0,t] = Isc_cell*(Ir[0,t]/1000.0)*(1+(T_co*(Temp[0,t]-25)));

    for x in range(0,len(V)):
        I[x,t] = Iph[0,t] - I0[0,t]*(exp((V[x,0]+I[x,t]*Rs)/(n1*Vt[0,t]))-1)-I02[0,t]*(exp((V[x,0]+I[x,t]*Rs)/(n2*Vt[0,t]))-1)-((V[x,0]+I[x,t]*Rs)/Rsh)
        P[x,t] = I[x,t]*V[x,0]
        x=x+1
t=t+1
```

P.s. Is there any solutions that I could avoid defining the parameters and their dimensions in advance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While running your code I saw that your variable `V` is 1D-array by initialization:

```
V = arange(0,0.7,0.01)
```

However, during your final computation of `I[x,t]` and `P[x,t]` you use a two-dimensional indexing of `V`. By replacing  `V[x,0]`with `V[x]`your code finishes without errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear RaJa. It works now but is there any difference between `V[0,x]` and `V[x]` since they both demonstrate a one dimensional vector? I ask this to learn more while I am new with Python.

Comment: I am so sorry that I cannot vote up while my reputations are not enough. Please accept my thanks in comment.

Comment: `V[x,0]`is a two-dimensional array, where the column-index is always zero. You could verify that by checking the shape with `V.shape` Something like `(100,)` would indicate a 1-dimensional array, while `(100,1)` is two-dimensional, even though it is "1-dimensional"